# sweetalert_1.default is not a function : Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, frontend, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm about discovering SweetAlert in the official [link](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) , so i wanted to use it in my app angular5 .

i have installed it this way :

```
npm install sweetalert --save
```

I have imported it in my component : edit-client.component with this :

```
  import swal from 'sweetalert';
```

Here is the  file editClient.component.ts  where i tried to use it  :

```
import swal from 'sweetalert';

Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-clients',
  templateUrl: './edit-clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-clients.component.scss']
})
export class EditClientsComponent implements OnInit {

EditClient(){
    this.clientService.updateClient(this.client)
      .subscribe(data=>{
        console.log(data);

        swal('mise a jour effecture !');

        this.router.navigate([ '../../../list' ], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
        },err=>{
        console.log(err);
        alert("Probleme");
      })
  }


}
```

But while running this exemple , i can't see the alert and i get an error instead :

```
RROR TypeError: sweetalert_1.default is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (edit-clients.component.ts:39)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:240)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:187)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:128)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: it seems to be working fine. here's the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdi3px?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: So weird , we're doing it the same way , but i keep getting the same error .

Comment: try importing like this - import * as sweetalert from 'sweetalert';

Comment: and then sweetalert("Hello world!");

Comment: I tried to do it but the sweetalert("Hello world!") show this message even before running :  Can't not invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Comment: @yer thank you for your help , i fixed it , i changed the import .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who faced the same problem i imported instead  :

```
import * as _swal from 'sweetalert';
import { SweetAlert } from 'sweetalert/typings/core';
const swal: SweetAlert = _swal as any;
```

And used then :

```
swal('hello world');
```

this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was importing from '***sweetalert***'. Once i correct the import statement, the problem was gone.

The correct import line was.

```
import swal from "sweetalert2";
```